# Why does a Connection enclosed in try with resources not allow any operations?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, try-with-resources

I want to use try with resources, though my program can not fulfill operations after connection is closed.

```
String conn = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?&serverTimeZone=Europe/Moscow&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( conn,"root","admin"))
   {
    return connection;
   } catch (SQLException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

My project is https://github.com/anatoliy19/1.1.3.git

Comment: That’s a clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource allocated in the try-with-resources block is closed when you leave the block. So when you return the connection, that connection is closed. The reference to the connection is still valid though and will not be GCed until it is no longer referenced.

You can think of it this way. If the connection returned here was not closed, when would the compiler know that it should close it? The compiler can not know that.

You should use the connection inside that block or manage closing the connection yourself and not use try-with-resources.

Comment: thanks, I thought that using try-with-resources gives me more respect.
Now I  see that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The try-with-resources statement ensures that each *resource* is closed at the end of this expression.

As [per contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), any object that

> implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`,

can be used as a resource.

The [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) interface extends `AutoClosable`.

Therefore, an implementation of the [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--) method is guaranteed to be called automatically at runtime via the try-with-resources construction. Calling `close()` results in:

> Closes this resource, relinquishing any underlying resources.

In case of a JDBC driver, communication with the database management system is "cut off“ in a normal and synchronous manner. Afterwards, the object you pass on (by returning it) is, practically speaking, useless.